# Unity2020, AdMob were built on mobile phones for testing, and after watching the advertisement, the overall sound of the game disappeared

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob

After watching the advertisement, when clicking on the close button in the upper right corner, Xcode reported an error and the game lost its overall sound. It can only be restored when the game is completely exited in the background and then re-entered. However, if you try to watch the advertisement again, the same thing will happen.
The following are two errors reported by xcode:

> Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>

> 0x130084480 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess NearSuspended Assertion' for process with PID=63,772, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}

This issue has already appeared before, and the reason for its triggering is not yet clear. This may be related to different phone types and environments.

In fact, it's difficult for us to try anything because the reason for this problem is not obvious. However, we still tried to modify the advertising access method to make it more stable. We did have some effects before, but now this situation has happened again.

If someone encounters the same problem, I really hope we can communicate and solve it together, or if someone has already solved such a problem. Thank you very much!